# difference in two modified multi-view CNNI

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, python, residual-networks

I am working on a dataset where i have two views of a same object( lateral and dorsal). I modified the RESNET50 to take the two views as input( as two different branches of CNN, till the last layer) and concatenate the features from the just before the classification, concatenate them to fC layer and then do the classification. I have two versions of it, and both give more or less same accuracy( >0.9). I am jst not sure what is the difference in these two architecture.
One is

## MULTI-VIEW CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORK (MVCNN) ARCHITECTURE 1

```
class MVCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000, pretrained=True):
        super(MVCNN, self).__init__()
       
        
        resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained = pretrained)
        
        fc_in_features = resnet.fc.in_features
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-1])
        self.fc = nn.Linear(fc_in_features * 2, fc_in_features)
        #self.adavaptivePooling = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(fc_in_features , 2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(2048, 2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(2048, num_classes)
        )
            
    def forward(self, inputs): # inputs.shape = samples x views x height x width x channels
        inputs = inputs.transpose(0, 1)
        view_features = [] 
        for view_batch in inputs:
            view_batch = self.features(view_batch)
            view_batch = view_batch.view(view_batch.shape[0], view_batch.shape[1:].numel())
            view_features.append(view_batch)   
            
        concat_views = torch.cat(view_features,-1)
        #pooled_views, _ = torch.max(torch.stack(view_features), 0)
        #outputs = self.classifier(pooled_views)
        outputs = self.fc(concat_views)
        
        outputs = self.classifier(outputs)
        return outputs
```

another one is

## MULTI-VIEW CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORK (MVCNN) ARCHITECTURE 2

```
class MVCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000, pretrained=True):
        super(MVCNN, self).__init__()
       
        
        resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained = pretrained)
        
        fc_in_features = resnet.fc.in_features
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-1])
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(fc_in_features , 2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(2048, 2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(2048, num_classes)
        )
            
    def forward(self, inputs): # inputs.shape = samples x views x height x width x channels
        inputs = inputs.transpose(0, 1)
        view_features = [] 
        for view_batch in inputs:
            view_batch = self.features(view_batch)
            view_batch = view_batch.view(view_batch.shape[0], view_batch.shape[1:].numel())
            view_features.append(view_batch)   
            
        concat_views = torch.cat(view_features,-1)
        #pooled_views, _ = torch.max(torch.stack(view_features), 0)
        #outputs = self.classifier(pooled_views)
        
        outputs = self.classifier(concat_views)
        return outputs
```

In both architecture, I am concatenating the features to FC layer. Is it safe to say, in 1st approach, I am adding extra FC layer, and in 2nd layer, I just used the last FC layer directly to concatenate the feature?